# Mapstruct : How do I map hierarchical structure where the child object is a list and have attributes which are lists

Tags: java, mapping, hierarchy, mapstruct

I have a scenario where I need to map from a DTO object to a Domain objects.

I have simplified the scenario below

```
class TopLevel {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private List<SecondLevel> secondLevel = new ArrayList<>();
    
    class SecondLevel {
        private String attr3;
        private JsonNode additionalConfig;
        private List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<ThirdLevel> thirdLevel = new ArrayList<>();

        class ThirdLevel {
            private String attr4;
            private String attr5;
            private List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<>();
            
        }  

    }  

}
```

This needs to be mapped to the domain structure below

```
class TopLevelDomain {
    private ID guid1; //Generated Guid
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private List<SecondLevelDomain> secondLevelDomain = new ArrayList<>();
}

class SecondLevelDomain {
    private ID guid1; //From TopLevel Domain
    private ID guid2; //Generated Guid
    private String attr3;
    private String stringListAsString; // List of Strings needs to be converted to string (JSON format)
    private String additionalConfig; //JSON node needs to be converted to String (JSON format)
    private List<ThirdLevelDomain> thirdLevelDomain = new ArrayList<>();
}

class ThirdLevelDomain {
    private ID guid1; //From TopLevel Domain
    private ID guid2; //From SecondLevel Guid
    private ID guid3; //New Guid
    private String attr4;
    private String attr5;
    private String anotherListAsString; // List of Strings needs to be converted to string (JSON format)

}
```

Now I need to do a qualifiedByName/Named mapping to get the GUID for the first level. Also I need similar GUID for the other 2 child levels as well.

```
@Mapping(source = "topLevel", target = "guid1", qualifiedByName = "mapGuid1")
@Mapping(source = "topLevel", target = "secondLevelDomain", qualifiedByName = "secondLevelDomain")
TopLevelDomain toTopLevel(TopLevel topLevel)
```

If I do something like the above code, I see no way how I can access the secondlevel attributes attr3, additionalConfig and the List stringList in the @Mapping annotation

Also how do I access the thirdlevel attributes attr4, attr5 and anotherList. I need to to direct mapping for the string mattributes, assign the guids and do some custom mapping for the List of String and JSONNodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that you want to do here.

1. Add additional mapping methods. Mapstruct will use user-defined mapping methods over generating new ones.
2. Use `@AfterMapping` to pass on the generated GUID's.

```
// custom mapping annotations
TopLevelDomain toTopLevel( TopLevel topLevel );

// custom mapping annotations
SecondLevelDomain toSecondLevel( TopLevel.SecondLevel secondLevel );

// custom mapping annotations
ThirdLevelDomain toThirdLevel( TopLevel.SecondLevel.ThirdLevel thirdLevel );

// custom mapping methods

@AfterMapping
default void handleGuidTransfer( TopLevelDomain topLevel ){
    for ( SecondLevelDomain secondLevel: topLevel.getSecondLevelDomain() ) {
        secondLevel.setGuid1( topLevel.getGuid1() );
        for ( ThirdLevelDomain thirdLevel: secondLevel.getThirdLevelDomain() ) {
            thirdLevel.setGuid1( topLevel.getGuid1() );
            thirdLevel.setGuid2( secondLevel.getGuid2() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. I have used almost the same approach here. Only thing is AfterMapping functionality does not play well with Lombok. Actually Lombok is fine, the AfterMapping functionality will not work if TopLevelDomain or SecondLevelDomain or ThirdLevelDomain, any of them have Lombok Builder annotation functionality defined. I did not really need Builder functionality for my application. So i removed that and then this approach worked beautifully. Thanks again for such a clear solution.